# Can't create thread in thread_group with a packaged_task

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I want to create a group of threads which all have futures (that's why I use packaged_tasks) so I can use values they return.
However the following code return an error during compilation:

```
boost::thread_group group;


for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    boost::packaged_task<int> task(std::bind(&matchThis,someStr, anotherStr));
    boost::unique_future<int> fi=task.get_future();

    //add task to task-group
    group.create_thread(boost::move(task));
    group.join_all();
}
```

This is the error:

> c:\boost\boost\thread\detail\thread_group.hpp:42: ERROR:
>   "boost::packaged_task::packaged_task": No access to private member which was declared in the boost::packaged_task-class
>   . with [
>    R=int]
>   ...

this code worked perfectly when I created a thread like this:

```
boost::thread thread(boost::move(task));
```

So what is wrong with using thread_groups instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're not using C++11 (because I think it would work if you were.)

`boost::thread` has been "move-enabled" so it can accept the simulated rvalue-references returned by `boost::move`.  `boost::thread_group` has not been "move-enabled" in the same way, so the argument to `create_thread` must be copyable, and a `packaged_task` is not copyable.

I would suggest checking the Boost Trac bug database and if there isn't one already adding a request for `create_thread` to support moved rvalues.